# Unable to display content on browser -AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and I have been learning from a book on AngularJs. I tried running one of the examples given in the book but I cannot see the content. This is the code

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title> Shopping Cart </title>
</head>
<body np-controller='CartController'>
 <h1>Your Order</h1>
 <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
  <span>{{item.title}}</span>
  <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
  <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
  <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
  <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
 </div>
 <script src="angular.js"></script>
 <script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 app.controller('CartController',function ($scope){
  $scope.items = [
   {
    title: 'Paint Pots',
    quantity: 8,
    price: 3.95
   },
   {
    title: 'Polka Dots',
    quantity: 17,
    price: 12.95
   },
   {
    title: 'Pebbles',
    quantity: 6,
    price: 6.95
   } 
  ];
  $scope.remove = function(index){
   $scope.items.splice(index,1);
  }
 })  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open in the browser all I see is "Your Order" and the rest is all blank. I checked the console but it has no errors. Can anyone help me with solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo there

```
ng-controller
```

instead of

```
np-controller
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't see that typo. it works now.